# $.jAlert is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

After having tried, jquery confirm, and now jAlert, I encounter the same error every time..
In console I get - TypeError: $.jAlert is not a function[Learn More]

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/jAlert.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jAlert.js"></script>
<script src="js/jAlert-functions.js"></script>
```

And the button I have is...

```
<input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" id="mybtn" value="">
```

And the script part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mybtn').on('click',function(){
    $.jAlert({
      'title': 'Nice Size',
      'content': 'This is the sized alert',
       'theme':'blue',
      'closeOnClick': true 
   });
});
</script>
```

jQuery and jAlert are conflicting I guess... 
Can anyone help?

Comment: check in network tab if  `jAlert` file is loaded

Comment: 200 GET localhost jquery-3.3.1.min.js script js 85.21 kB 84.89 kB 11 ms
200 GET localhost jAlert.css stylesheet css 65.05 kB 64.75 kB 15 ms
200 GET localhost jAlert.js script js 26.53 kB 26.22 kB 20 ms 
200 GET localhost jAlert-functions.js script js 2.36 kB 2.04 kB 17 ms

Comment: use browsers console to determine if script is loaded properly - type $.jAlert() and check if response us correct

Comment: https://www.jquery-az.com/jquery/demo.php?ex=22.0_3

Comment: @לבנימלכה I am using the same structure, but still i get the same error.

Comment: @Raphael I tried typing $.jAlert() in console and it says not a function.

Comment: try `typeof $.jAlert`

Comment: @VishnuPrasad.R - I would check if multiple jQuery versions are present in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting extending jquery functionality with fn so your code will be

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#mybtn').on('click',function(){
      $.fn.jAlert({
      'title': 'Nice Size',
      'content': 'This is the sized alert',
      'theme':'blue',
      'closeOnClick': true 
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: $.fn.jAlert() is not a function